# Anychart does not display dates and times on x axis when data is spaced at hourly intervals

Tags: javascript, anychart

There are plenty of Anychart HTML examples available for download of line charts with a date-time x axis. All the examples I've seen have data spaced at intervals of weeks or months. When I modify the sample code such that the data spans only a few hours, nothing is printed on the x axis.

For instance, I've downloaded the example at https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/AGST_DateTime_Axes_02, which uses the following data:

```
  var series = chart.line([
    {value: 1.172, x: Date.UTC(2003, 09, 14)},
    {value: 1.916, x: Date.UTC(2004, 09, 13)},
    {value: 5.57, x: Date.UTC(2005, 09, 13)},
    {value: 15.0, x: Date.UTC(2006, 09, 13)},
    {value: 144, x: Date.UTC(2007, 09, 13)}
  ]);
```

This works fine for me, with Jan 2004, Jul 2004 etc displayed on the x axis.

However, when I change this data to the following:

```
  var series = chart.line([
    {value: 1.172, x: Date.UTC(2003, 09, 13, 9, 40, 0)},
    {value: 1.916, x: Date.UTC(2003, 09, 13, 10, 41, 0)},
    {value: 5.57, x: Date.UTC(2003, 09, 13, 11, 41, 0)},
    {value: 15.0, x: Date.UTC(2003, 09, 13, 12, 40, 0)},
    {value: 144, x: Date.UTC(2003, 09, 13, 13, 39, 0)}
  ]);
```

The chart is displayed, but nothing is displayed on the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kind of misconfiguration. In the sample you mentioned, line 18 is the following:
`dateTimeTicks.interval(0, 6);`
It means to show ticks every 6 hours on the xAxis. But in your second case, the whole range of data is less than 6 hours (between 9 and 13 hours), so that's why you see no ticks.
To avoid it, just remove that line or adjust intervals according to your data range. Here is [the result](https://playground.anychart.com/wZn388fT).
You can learn more about this function in [the API Reference](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.scales.DateTimeTicks#interval).

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation and example.